# How do I synchronise two MySQL databases using a Cronjob PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql, database, cron, synchronization

i'm developing a webshop with a MySQL database for a client.
This client already invoice management website with a MySQL database.

Now I want to write a php script thats triggered by a cronjob to sync invoice, client and product records.

*order record:*

```
id | clientId | status | shipping | reduction
```

*order_items records:*

```
id | productId | price |amount | orderId
```

*client record:*

```
id | fname | name | email | ...
```

Note that only order records with `status = 2` should be synchronised, after they have been synchronised, the status should change to `3`.

Both databases are using different tables for orders and invoices

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: If you have the option of stored procedures this could be a good way of executing the database calls. Then you would just need your cron job to execute that procedure. Alternatively the cron job could execute a PHP file with the relevant SQL updates.

Answer (score 0):

1) Select records 
2) Loop over records
3) start transaction (optional)
4) Insert records in db2
5) Update records in db1
6) commit

Answer (score 0):

Are the databases runing on seperate instances of MySQL?

If so...

> What is the best way to do this?

Use the same database structure on both systems and use mysql's asynchronous replication.

Failing that, use the federated engine to access tables from one instance on the other, then follow the procedure for same instance below.

If on same MySQL instance....

Make sure you've got an indexed update timestamp on every source table you want to sync and copy the records which are eligible for copying and which have been modified since the last capture.

Answer (score 0):

**you could look into some phpclasses that do this for you http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?words=mysql+sync&x=0&y=0&go_search=1

Source :- [How can i synchronize two database tables with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626192/how-can-i-synchronize-two-database-tables-with-php)**