# How to maintain wordpress production and development webs?

Tags: wordpress, git, production

this question is on the table already few years, but so far I didn't find any useful solution. So I ask again - maybe in last years any possibility appeared. Here is what I need to solve:

I have production web (online) and I have development web (also online, as I need my client to see the changes and check them before going to production). Obviously on busy website I cannot stop adding comments/orders/products/posts at production web for let's say 3 days, clone it to development site, do my changes and clone it back to production site.

I'm not speaking about some WP core developmet, plugins or themes. Just standard design changes, sometimes new method via snippet, etc.

So how do you do this?

I'm aware of GIT, but that doesn't solve the database :(

THanx for your ideas and best practice sharing.

Maros

Comment: The company I work for used to do web development heavily on WP, we used a tool called [Trellis](https://roots.io/trellis/). It allows users to source control your WP project in a better way because they've split the core part of WP and the themes and plugins. With this and the help of [wp-migrate-db](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) (I do recommend the pro version as it can migrate other assets than just DB) plugin we were able to deploy WP websites through local dev (device) => Staging (cloud) => Production (cloud) and vice-versa when we need to pull/push data back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

Using an automatic cron job to sync db and/or files will do it
it can also be triggered automatically on interval or on need

bs: it will work on shared hosts

Comment: could you please be little more specific on the idea? I understand cron as a kind of automatic scheduling system. That said, it can trigger something, but cannot do itself the db sync. Or am I wrong? if I am correct, then I need something else than just cron, right?

Comment: here is a stack that discussed this before 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626192/how-can-i-synchronize-two-database-tables-with-php

Comment: This looks like reinventing the wheel kind of an idea to me. With regards to the question, you can use something like [wp-migrate-db](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) to sync back and forth the database as needed.